# Latest Azure Java client SDK can't check that a Subscription exists

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics

I have been trying to write a Topic Subscriber which can check to see if it's subscription and rules already exist. And if so just connect otherwise create the subscription, but the new 1.1.0 client API doesn't have a way to query a Topic for it's subscriptions. And the management API requires a AD authentication which my app should not need, it only has access to the connection string. Is there a way to do what I need to or do I have to go back to the 0.9.x version of the service bus APIs? Which seem to have more functionality than the 1.x APIs.